# reading data from website into variable in Java using java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to fetch data from an url and dump it into "content" instance variable. Both the `url` and the `content` should be initialized in the contructor. The `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` are also involved but being completely new to Java I can't make sense of that. Here's the code:

```
public class NewsFinder {

// Instance variables
private String url;
private String content;
private Scanner s;

// Getter methods
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

// Constructor
public NewsFinder(String url) {
    this.url = url;

    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream());
        if (s.hasNextLine()) {
            this.s = s.nextLine();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public boolean isInNews(Object o) {
    if (((String) o).contains(content)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't name the local variable in the constructor `s`, that's the name of your `String`. Also, is your `content` in `content` or in `s`?

Comment: Read [`hasNextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) and [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) docs. It will start making sense :)

Comment: hasNextLine() should be in while loop to read complete content from stream... You can read java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: String content = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream()).useDelimiter("\\Z").next(); might be something that you might want to try.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream());
if (s.hasNextLine()) {
    this.s = s.nextLine();
}
```

Logically, this part of code should be replaced by :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream());
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    this.s += s.nextLine();
}
```

---

Personnaly, I would use an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to achieve this.

**Example**

```
URL url; InputStream is; BufferedReader br; String line; StringBuilder sb;
try{
    url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
    is = url.openStream();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    sb = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        sb.append(line);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        if(is != null){
        is.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---